# What is the official specification for PMML substring handling of long strings?

Tags: pmml

Given a substring Definition of

```
<Apply function="substring">
  <FieldRef field="Input"/>
  <Constant>1</Constant>
  <Constant>2</Constant>
</Apply>
```

What is the official specification on what will happen if the string "helloworld" is the input?

Is it not allowed, or should something else occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the specification of [PMML built-in function "substring"](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-2-1/BuiltinFunctions.html#substring), which is based on [XQuery built-in function "substring"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-substring).
In Java, your expression translates to the following `input.substring((1 - 1), (1 - 1) + 2)`.

The important thing to notice is that in PMML and XQuery the indexing of strings starts from position `1` (not `0`). Also, there is no such thing as `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when working with this function. If you are interested in obtaining the remainder of a string, then you can pass an arbitrarily large number as the `length` argument.

Comment: Looks like the JPMML-Evaluator library did not implement the `substring` built-in function correctly for out-of-range argument values. This has been fixed in the latest commit `b4c8cdf0dd`.